# Add the Custom Data in top of every post title in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to add the custom data in the top of every post in wordpress. Previously what i am tried is to be looks like this way

```
function newcontent($content) {
ob_start();
```

// Some stuff goes here
echo "this is for testing";

```
$newvariable = ob_get_clean();
return $content.$newvariable;
}
add_filter('the_content','newcontent');
```

is that output comes like

Let consider this is the post

> **POST TITLE**
>
> ```
> this is for testing // appending message to the content
>
> // POST CONTENT
> ```

Is there is a way to show the sample data  in the top of every post i mean above the title ?

Not sure there might be a way :)

Any suggestion would be great:)

Thanks,
vicky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but...

```
function insert_before_title($title){
    return '<h1> before the title </h1>'.$title;
}

add_filter('the_title', 'insert_before_title');
```

Just filter the title as opposed to the content.

Comment: Yes thanks for your super fast reply :) I tried this too but i adding the sample data to every title i mean in the navigation left sidebar and right side content title like that. I make the condition too like is_single() but still for the post page with sample data is come's up !!!

Comment: @Fresher Are you saying that you want to insert before the `widget_title` too? if so, just add `add_filter('widget_title', 'insert_before_title');`